# Is it a thread-safe mechanism?

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety

Is this class thread-safe?

```
class Counter {
  private ConcurrentMap<String, AtomicLong> map = 
    new ConcurrentHashMap<String, AtomicLong>();
  public long add(String name) {
    if (this.map.get(name) == null) {
      this.map.putIfAbsent(name, new AtomicLong());
    }
    return this.map.get(name).incrementAndGet();
  }
}
```

What do you think?

Comment: Have you quantified the cost of creating AtomicLongs? Unless you create zillions of them it will most likely be unnoticeable.

Comment: @assylias you're right, Aaron explained the problem below already (+1 to your answer)

Comment: See my updated answer with timing (to be adjusted to your use case).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, provided you make the map final. The if is not necessary but you can keep it for performance reasons if you want, although it will most likely not make a noticeable difference:

```
public long add(String name) {
  this.map.putIfAbsent(name, new AtomicLong());
  return this.map.get(name).incrementAndGet();
}
```

**EDIT**

For the sake of it, I have quickly tested both implementation (with and without the check). 10 millions calls on the same string take:

- 250 ms with the check
- 480 ms without the check

Which confirms what I said: unless you call this method millions of time or it is in performance critical part of your code, it does not make a difference.

**EDIT 2**

Full test result - see the **`BetterCounter` which yields even better results**. Now the test is very specific (no contention + the get always works) and does not necessarily correspond to your usage.

> Counter: 482 ms
>   LazyCounter: 207 ms
>   MPCounter: 303 ms
>   BetterCounter: 135 ms

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
        Counter count = new Counter();
        LazyCounter lazyCount = new LazyCounter();
        MPCounter mpCount = new MPCounter();
        BetterCounter betterCount = new BetterCounter();

        //WARM UP
        for (int i = 0; i < 10_000_000; i++) {
            count.add("abc");
            lazyCount.add("abc");
            mpCount.add("abc");
            betterCount.add("abc");
        }

        //TEST
        long start = System.nanoTime();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10_000_000; i++) {
            count.add("abc");
        }
        long end = System.nanoTime();
        System.out.println((end - start) / 1000000);

        start = System.nanoTime();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10_000_000; i++) {
            lazyCount.add("abc");
        }
        end = System.nanoTime();
        System.out.println((end - start) / 1000000);

        start = System.nanoTime();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10_000_000; i++) {
            mpCount.add("abc");
        }
        end = System.nanoTime();
        System.out.println((end - start) / 1000000);

        start = System.nanoTime();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10_000_000; i++) {
            betterCount.add("abc");
        }
        end = System.nanoTime();
        System.out.println((end - start) / 1000000);        
    }

    static class Counter {

        private final ConcurrentMap<String, AtomicLong> map =
                new ConcurrentHashMap<String, AtomicLong>();

        public long add(String name) {
            this.map.putIfAbsent(name, new AtomicLong());
            return this.map.get(name).incrementAndGet();
        }
    }

    static class LazyCounter {

        private final ConcurrentMap<String, AtomicLong> map =
                new ConcurrentHashMap<String, AtomicLong>();

        public long add(String name) {
            if (this.map.get(name) == null) {
                this.map.putIfAbsent(name, new AtomicLong());
            }
            return this.map.get(name).incrementAndGet();
        }
    }

    static class BetterCounter {

        private final ConcurrentMap<String, AtomicLong> map =
                new ConcurrentHashMap<String, AtomicLong>();

            public long add(String name) {
                AtomicLong counter = this.map.get(name);
                if (counter != null)
                    return counter.incrementAndGet();

                AtomicLong newCounter = new AtomicLong();
                counter = this.map.putIfAbsent(name, newCounter);

                return (counter == null ? newCounter.incrementAndGet() : counter.incrementAndGet());
            }
    }

    static class MPCounter {

        private final ConcurrentMap<String, AtomicLong> map =
                new ConcurrentHashMap<String, AtomicLong>();

        public long add(String name) {
            final AtomicLong newVal = new AtomicLong(),
                    prevVal = map.putIfAbsent(name, newVal);
            return (prevVal != null ? prevVal : newVal).incrementAndGet();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Without `if` we instantiate a lot of `AtomicLong` objects, which is time consuming and redundant

Comment: @yegor256: It might feel redundant but that doesn't prove that it's time consuming. Depending on the names that you use, creating too many `AtomicLong`s could be cheaper than searching the map 3-4 times.

Comment: @assylias: `putIfAbsent()` returns the current instance, so you can also get rid of the call to `get()`

Comment: @AaronDigulla no, `putIfAbsent()` returns **previous** value, which is `NULL`

Comment: i agree with @yegor256, this will be horribly inefficient if called frequently.  JensBorgland has the right solution.

Comment: is that timing before or after the jit kicked in?  also, the timing doesn't necessarily show the affects on the gc.

Comment: @jtahlborn: The JIT kicks in when a method is executed more than 10000 times (default hotspot settings).

Comment: so, your timing is from after your warmed up the jit?  also, you testing doesn't show the affects on concurrency.  instantiating AtomicLongs most likely generates additional memory barriers.

Comment: I start with a run on 10 millions without timing, then I measure the time of another 10 millions run. So the JIT should have done its job.

Comment: side note, what version are you using for the "other" option?  i just realized i suggested JesBorgland's answer, but' it's not correct.  i thought it had used the return value from putIfAbsent correctly, but doesn't seem to now.

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT**

Yes if you make the map `final`. Otherwise, it's not guaranteed that all threads see the most recent version of the map data structure when they call `add()` for the first time.

Several threads can reach the body of the `if()`. The `putIfAbsent()` will make sure that only a single `AtomicLong` is put into the map.

There should be no way that `putIfAbsent()` can return without the new value being in the map.

So when the second `get()` is executed, it will never get a `null` value and since only a single `AtomicLong` can have been added to the map, all threads will get the same instance.

**[EDIT2]** The next question: How efficient is this?

This code is faster since it avoids unnecessary searches:

```
public long add(String name) {
    AtomicLong counter = map.get( name );
    if( null == counter ) {
        map.putIfAbsent( name, new AtomicLong() );
        counter = map.get( name ); // Have to get again!!!
    }
    return counter.incrementAndGet();
}
```

This is why I prefer Google's [CacheBuilder](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v12.0/javadoc/com/google/common/cache/CacheBuilder.html) which has a method that is called when a key can't be found. That way, the map is searched only once *and* I don't have to create extra instances.

Comment: @PéterTörök With `putIfAbsent` ?

Comment: @assylias, hmmm, yes, I was a bit too fast :-) Comment removed.

Comment: Sorry, missed the `IfAbsent()`. Fixed my answer.

Comment: In your [EDIT2] you are commiting the common fallacy of assuming that `putIfAbsent` returns the new value under key wheras in fact it returns the **previous** value -- which is `null` when the key was absent. It's kind of retarded API, rarely useful, but there it is.

Comment: Oh... f****. Well, it makes sense to keep it in line with the normal `put()`.

Comment: Okay, I fixed the code. This should be the fastest way to do it: One get in the standard case and a get after `putIfAbsent()` to get the current value which might have been set by another thread.

Comment: Yes, that's kind of a rationale for it, but in reality it's just a pain in the ass and -- as both you and assylias, and even I in an earlier question found out, it is in fact NOT the intuitive expectation. Not to mention it makes us write all that extra code for no benefit.

Comment: BTW I don't think you are forced to get it again. If the return value of `putIfAbsent` is `null`, then use the instance you tried to put, otherwise use the instance returned from `putIfAbsent`. Performance-wise this makes an important difference.

Answer (score 1):

No one seems to have the complete solution, which is:

```
  public long add(String name) {
    AtomicLong counter = this.map.get(name);
    if (counter == null) {
      AtomicLong newCounter = new AtomicLong();
      counter = this.map.putIfAbsent(name, newCounter);
      if(counter == null) {
        counter = newCounter;
      }
    }

    return counter.incrementAndGet();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

What about this:

```
class Counter {

  private final ConcurrentMap<String, AtomicLong> map = 
    new ConcurrentHashMap<String, AtomicLong>();

  public long add(String name) {
    this.map.putIfAbsent(name, new AtomicLong());
    return this.map.get(name).incrementAndGet();
  }
}
```

- The `map` should be `final` to guarantee it is fully visible to all threads before the first method is invoked. (see [17.5 final Field Semantics (Java Language Specification)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.5) for details)
- I think the `if` is redundant, I hope I'm not overseeing anything.

Edit: Added a quote from the Java Language Specification:

Comment: OK, just make sure entries aren't removed once added.

Comment: Each call to your `add` instantiates an `AtomicLong`. That's avoided in OP's example.

Comment: Making the `map` `final` would be good practise (and would prevent someone from later accidentially adding a method that recreates the map) but wouldn't actually effect the visibility (since it's created when the class is instantiated).

Comment: @Jens: There is no memory barrier when the constructor returns. So other threads could have stale memory in their caches.

Comment: @AaronDigulla Your actually right. I had to fetch my "Java Concurrency in Practice" and unless the Counter instance is safely published you're right. I hate being wrong but this taught me something, thanks!

Comment: @JensBorgland: I didn't know about this for years. I learned it by accident in a presentation ;-) Scary...

Comment: @AaronDigulla Even with `final` it will not be threadsafe if it allows the `this` to escape from the constructor! Now THAT's scary :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you would be better off with something like this:

```
class Counter { 
  private ConcurrentMap<String, AtomicLong> map = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, AtomicLong>();

  public long add(String name) {
    AtomicLong counter = this.map.get(name);
    if (counter == null) {
      AtomicLong newCounter = new AtomicLong();
      counter = this.map.putIfAbsent(name, newCounter);
      if (counter == null) {
        // The new counter was added - use it
        counter = newCounter;
      }
    }

    return counter.incrementAndGet();
  }
}
```

Otherwise multiple threads may add simultaneously and you wouldn't notice (since you ignore the value returned by putIfAbsent).

I assume that you never recreate the map.

Comment: You example is just longer, not better

Comment: That works but I'm not sure I understand your comment "Otherwise multiple threads may add simultaneously and you wouldn't notice" - what do you mean?

Comment: It's a bit faster since it searches the map only 2 times at most. The code in the question searches the map at least three times.

Comment: Sorry, I just realized that your original solution actually is thread safe... What I meant was that you don't use the value returned by putIfAbsent but since you always retrieve the counter from the map right before incrementing it it doesn't matter. My solution has the benefit of avoiding one get operation however.

Comment: @JensBorgland It contains the same error as in other posts: putIfAbsent will return null the first time and the add method will throw a NPE.

Answer (score 0):

This solution (note that I am showing only the body of the `add` method -- the rest stays the same!) spares you of any calls to `get`:

```
final AtomicLong newVal = new AtomicLong(), 
                 prevVal = map.putIfAbsent(name, newVal);
return (prevVal != null? prevVal : newVal).incrementAndGet();
```

In all probability an extra `get` is much costlier than an extra `new AtomicLong()`.

Comment: This is actually slightly slower than the OP's version.

Comment: True, if you go with OP's version, that's the fastest since `putIfAbsent` still implies a `get`.